# lubuntu - Help with partition, root, space, kfmclient

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, lubuntu, disk-usage

I'm new in Linux, so I decided to install Lubuntu, but I must have installed in the wrong way at the time of the partition and I ended up allocating only 5GB for the system (of a 500GB hard drive), and that's it. Now using lubuntu I finally realized after installing some updates and having done some downloads that I am with "full disk". I tried installing PyCharm and firefox alerts with these warnings;

*1. /tmp/mozilla_fireblox0/dJxNCdU_.gz.part could not be saved because the source file could not be read.
Please try again later or contact the server administrator.
2. There is not enough space to save /tmp/mozilla_fireblox0/+BoPvAEp.gz.part.
Free up disk space and try again or save the file to another location*.

Also, when I press 'WIN Key + E' to go to my files it alerts me with the message of 'kfmclient'; *failed to execute child process 'kfmclient' (File or directory not found)*

I tried to partition the rest of the disk in Preferences - Disk, but I must have done it the wrong way because I still can not update nor install programs for "lack of space". What I had to do before asking for help is to realize that I have a problem with correct partitioning. Also, my ROOT folder '/' shows 'Total: 4,5 GB'

Can you please help me, and if you can, can you help me solve this problem with Terminal?

Comment: You can only increase the root partition when booted from a LiveUSB stick. During the LiveUSB boot, select Try Ubuntu. Then run `gparted` to increase the partition.

Comment: And if you don't mind restarting from scratch, delete the 5GB partition and install again.

Comment: but in installation, how can I do the correct partition?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can fix it, or you can backup your things and reinstall. Honestly, backing up /home and reinstalling would make life and things more easier for you.

If you want to fix it, download and create a bootable usb stick or cd/dvd-rom with [gpartd](https://gparted.org/livecd.php).

Then expand the file system. Also check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDgUwWkvuIY) on how to use gpartd.

Comment: It worked. i'm using Ubuntu 16 now. Valeu Luis!